# How to extract lines/text present in between multiple instances of same special character in a file

Tags: python, shell, bioinformatics

**Input file: seq.gb**

//

LOCUS      **NC_12345**               299 bp ss-RNA     linear   VRL 1-11-1

DEFINITION  xyz

ACCESSION

FEATURES             Location/Qualifiers

source          1..29903

/organism="ABC2"

/mol_type="genomic RNA"

/isolate="xyz"

/host="jgdg"

/db_xref="taxon:123456"

/country="wf"

/collection_date="Dec-2011"

5'UTR           1..265

gene            266..21555

/gene="jgn"

CDS             join(266..13468,13468..21555)

//

LOCUS      **NC_23232**               29903 bp ss-RNA     linear   VRL 18-MAR-2020

DEFINITION  xyz

ACCESSION

FEATURES             Location/Qualifiers

source          1..29903

/organism="ABC2"

/mol_type="genomic RNA"

/isolate="xyz"

/host="jgdg"

/db_xref="taxon:123456"

/country="wf"

/collection_date="Dec-2011"

5'UTR           1..265

gene            266..21555

/gene="jgn"

CDS             join(266..13468,13468..21555)

//

**I want to extract the text present between // ..... // and want to save it individually in different files like this:**

**output file1 : NC_12345.gb**

LOCUS      **NC_12345**               299 bp ss-RNA     linear   VRL 1-11-1

DEFINITION  xyz

ACCESSION

FEATURES             Location/Qualifiers

source          1..299

/organism="ABC2"

/mol_type="genomic RNA"

/isolate="xyz"

/host="jgdg"

/db_xref="taxon:123456"

/country="wf"

/collection_date="Dec-2011"

5'UTR           1..265

gene            266..2155

/gene="jgn"

CDS             join(266..1346,1346..2155)

**output file2 : NC_23232.gb**

LOCUS      NC_23232               299 bp ss-RNA     linear   VRL 2-2-2

DEFINITION  xyz

ACCESSION

FEATURES             Location/Qualifiers

source          1..299

/organism="ABC2"

/mol_type="genomic RNA"

/isolate="xyz"

/host="jgdg"

/db_xref="taxon:123456"

/country="wf"

/collection_date="Dec-2011"

5'UTR           1..265

gene            266..2155

/gene="jgn"

CDS             join(266..1346,1346..2155)

**I have 1200 such records in single file and i want to separate them to 1200 individual files. How to do it?**

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
import re
# open your source file here and read it to a string variable
with open ('source.txt', mode='r') as src:
    src_read = src.read()

src_list = src_read.split('//')

regex = re.compile('LOCUS ([A-Z]+_[0-9]+\s)')
for content in src_list:
    if (filename := re.search(regex, content)):
        with open(f'{filename.group(1)}.gb', mode='w') as fh:
            fh.write(content)
```